# JTable CustomRenderer Issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have created one Jtable.This table consist of two columns name and timestamp. I want to make color of row yellow if name is "jane". Following is the code for that :-

```
    class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        String name = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();

        if (name.trim().equals("jane")) {
            c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

However instead of changing color of row to yellow for particular name, it is changing color of every row.I am setting data of table as following

```
tableModelName = (DefaultTableModel)jTableName.getModel();

jTableName.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new CustomRenderer());

for(int i=0; i<records.size(); i++)
         {
            tableModelName.addRow(records.get(i));          

         }
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Make sure to use `table.convertRowIndexToModel()` and `table.convertColumnIndexToModel()` before accessing the model. Else, any table sorting or column reordering will make your code fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an `else` clause to set the background color to something besides yellow if the name is not "jane". A single renderer instance is used for all rendering, so once you set the color to yellow on that instance, it stays yellow.

Take a look at the JTable source code to see how the built-in renderers work:

```
    if (isSelected) {
        setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    }
    else {
        setForeground(table.getForeground());
        setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
```

For an easier way of doing this, you might try subclassing JTable and overriding [prepareRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29). This is handy for changes that affect entire rows like this, so you can use custom renderers for the individual cells, and tweak all renderers for a row in the `prepareRenderer` method.