# Default color of JTable row

Tags: java, swing, background, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have written one program where I am highlighting certain rows based on criteria.I posted one question regarding that :- [JTable CustomRenderer Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631535/jtable-customrenderer-issue)

Solution given for this problem was that I need to set color in else for rows which do not come under criteria. So I decided that in else I will use default color of `JTable`. Modified code is

```
else{
           c.setForeground(DefaultLookup.getColor(this, ui, "Table.dropCellForeground")); 
           c.setBackground(DefaultLookup.getColor(this, ui, "Table.dropCellBackground"));
        }
```

So far so good, I am getting required behaviour, but when I am trying to make jar following warning is coming :-

> warning: DefaultLookup is internal proprietary API and may be removed
>   in a future release

So can any one suggest me if there is any other way to setting rows to default color in `JTable`.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), demonstrated a.m. issue, short, runnable, compilable, no idea whats wrong from this description

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replacing `DefaultLookup.getColor(this, ui, "Table.dropCellForeground")` with
`javax.swing.UIManager.getColor("Table.dropCellForeground")` should fix your problem.

Also you can modify (globally) the default values present in your Look & Feel just by using the `put(Object key, Object value)` method from [UIManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html)

Comment: See this answer for how to get the color keys.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730649/swing-uimanager-getcolor-keys

Comment: See this URL for a list of color keys.  http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-uimanager-color-keys-list